# I cannot understand a formula related to soft voting in ensemble method

Tags: probability, machine-learning

I'm now in the middle of learining *soft voting* on

**Z. H. Zhou, Ensemble Methods: Foundations and Algorithms,
CRC Press, Taylor & Francis Group, Boca Raton, FL, 2012.**

And there is a thing that I cannot understand.

In this publication, there is a formula describing *weighted soft voting*, and there is a part I don't know what it is.

[image: formula 4.28]

In this complex formula, there is a part subtracting a value from a function *I(args)* and I have no idea what this function is about.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have not access the original paper. Probably it is an indicator function, meaning that when $f(x_k) = c_j$, it is equal to $1$; otherwise it is equal to $0$.

Comment: I guess you're right. Since the function is all about getting *euclidean norm* for linear multiplication subtracted by labeled value, it can be treated as indicator function